# Change Type of (Standard) registry key (REG_SZ -> REG_EXPAND_SZ) once

Tags: windows, registry

When you create a new key there is always a (Standard) value inside, which is a REG_SZ.
In one case I want it to be a REG_EXPAND_SZ.
How do I do it?
I want to do this so I can link a custom URI protocol to a file that can only be found via %APPDATA%. If you put a path with a sysvar like that in a REG_SZ it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RegSetKeyValue and set dwType argument set to REG_EXPAND_SZ.